# How Do I Find Good Graphic Designers for my Web Application Projects?

Tags: web-applications, graphics

While this isn't strictly programming related, it's something I've run into as a web developer on several occasions, and I imagine others have run into as well. For that reason, I hope this question can remain open.

As web developers, we know how to make our applications work. But clients/customers/visitors aren't necessarily happy with a system that just works, they want a site with some graphic personality. Something that "looks pretty".

Whether it's "trendy", "professional", "cool", or "grungy", there's always a feeling that a web site needs to give it's audience, in conjunction with the functionality of the site itself.

Unfortunately, a Google search for "web designer", returns a list of everybody in the world who owns a copy of MS FrontPage and/or PhotoShop.

So the questions are:

Where do you turn when you need a (talented) designer on your project?

What criteria do you use to determine if a designer candidate has skills, or is qualified?

Comment: Please, DO NOT CLOSE THIS.  I'm aware it's subjective, but I've run across the exact same problem on countless occasions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

37Signals recently launched [Haystack](http://haystack.com/) to address exactly this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've been looking through the samples on there, and it's odd- this is one industry where you DONT get what you pay for. There's "under $3000" designers with good looking stuff, and "over $50,000" designers with awful looking sites.

Comment: This is the reason that I prefer not to use sites like this. You can find very good and ridiculously cheap designers by word of mouth.

Comment: A lot of times the "awful looking" sites are awful because if the inisitance of the client... just keep that in mind. Of course i personally like to leave the "awful" sites out of my port but i guess some people dont.

Answer (score 3):

Designer freelance sites.

These are sites where you post a project, and the designers each post their proposals.  
You choose the one you are happy with.

Believe it or, you will get lots of quality offerings - almost too many.

Nothing else even comes close.

1. [99 Designs](http://99designs.com/)
2. [Crowdspring](http://www.crowdspring.com/)

(The latter is my favorite)

Also, some good points here: http://blog.siteroller.net/tips-when-looking-for-a-web-developer

Answer (score 1):

1. Freelancing/marketplace websites. You can make a post for a job you need done, sometimes however you really need to go out and look at the design offers that graphic designers post, it might take a bit of work to find a really good one, they won't always come to you. Sites such as:

   - http://www.getafreelancer.com/
   - http://marketplace.sitepoint.com/
   - http://www.talkfreelance.com/
   - http://www.elance.com/
2. I usually look at their portfolio and make sure they have nice graphical skills, as well as decent communication skills as indicated by the content they have on their website.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to find a website design that looks good to you and maybe a few of your end users. Find out who designed it and then ask them if they would be available for a side-project or full time employment. If they don't have the time, I am sure they would have friends to suggest to you. As always, be sure to see the portfolio of any graphic design before hiring them and perhaps ask them some questions about their design for your specific project. I wouldn't suggest templates because they often force you to build your website function around the design instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the quality of designers there, but there should be some overlap on [Rent a Coder](http://www.rentacoder.com/RentACoder/DotNet/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can search for templates instead of designers (to pick one example, [Get Template](http://www.gettemplate.com/)): a template is like a designer distilled (and much cheaper). Having done that you could also contact the designers of some templates that you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look on [Odesk.com](http://odesk.com). They seem to have some nice professionals with lots of feedback.

Answer (score -1):

I hate to advertise for myself on here, but I can't help but suggest you visit my website, and look under the portfolio tab, the url is in my profile.

Comment: If you hate to advertise yourself on here, then don't!